# MySQL get single column value of last record

Tags: mysql, join

I have a **query** which looks like:

```
SELECT max(sp.id) as max_id, p.name as player, max(update_time) as last_seen, min(login_time) as first_seen, s.name as last_server,
    sum(sp.play_time) as ontime_total,
    sum(case when login_time > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY then sp.play_time end) as ontime_day,
    sum(case when login_time > NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY then sp.play_time end) as ontime_week,
    sum(case when login_time > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH then sp.play_time end) as ontime_month
    FROM session_player sp
    INNER JOIN players p ON p.id=sp.player_id
    INNER JOIN server s ON s.id=sp.server_id
    WHERE p.name = ?
```

**The result:**
[image]

**The issue:**
Node22 isn't the last server. I am struggling on finding a way to get the server of the last record within this query. How would you solve this issue, if possible without running a second query.

(This query already takes 2-3s seconds depending on the user, if possible I would like to avoid any overhead and in case you see performance optimization possibilities I would appreciate anything.)

This would work, but its performance you can guess (4-5s):

```
SELECT
    MAX( sp.id ) AS max_id, p.name AS player, MAX( update_time ) AS last_seen, MIN( login_time ) AS first_seen, 
    SUM( sp.play_time ) AS ontime_total, 
    SUM( CASE WHEN login_time > NOW( ) - INTERVAL 1 DAY THEN sp.play_time END ) AS ontime_day, 
    SUM( CASE WHEN login_time > NOW( ) - INTERVAL 7 DAY THEN sp.play_time END ) AS ontime_week,
    SUM( CASE WHEN login_time > NOW( ) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH THEN sp.play_time END ) AS ontime_month,
    (SELECT s.name
        FROM session_player sp
        JOIN players p ON p.id=sp.player_id
        JOIN server s ON s.id=sp.server_id
        WHERE p.name = ?
        ORDER BY sp.id DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) as last_server
    FROM session_player sp
    INNER JOIN players p ON p.id = sp.player_id
    INNER JOIN server s ON s.id = sp.server_id
    WHERE p.name = ?
```

Comment: How are you defining "last record"?

Comment: On performance - make sure that the fields player.id,server.id,session_player.player_id and session_player.server_id are all indexed and (for myisam at least) that they are the first item in the index.

Comment: @MarcusAdams max id on the `session_player` table

Comment: @Giles they are already indexed due to the foreign key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After nearly 3 hours of experimenting I got it and even 260 times faster as before:

```
SELECT MAX(pd.id) AS max_id, pd.name AS player, MAX( pd.update_time ) AS last_seen, MIN( pd.login_time ) AS first_seen,
    SUM( pd.play_time ) AS ontime_total, 
    SUM( CASE WHEN pd.login_time > NOW( ) - INTERVAL 1 DAY THEN pd.play_time END ) AS ontime_day, 
    SUM( CASE WHEN pd.login_time > NOW( ) - INTERVAL 7 DAY THEN pd.play_time END ) AS ontime_week,
    SUM( CASE WHEN pd.login_time > NOW( ) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH THEN pd.play_time END ) AS ontime_month,
    (SELECT s.name
        FROM session_player sp
        INNER JOIN server s ON s.id=sp.server_id
        WHERE max(pd.id)=sp.id
    ) as last_server
FROM (
    SELECT sp.id AS id, sp.server_id as server_id, p.name AS name, sp.login_time AS login_time, sp.update_time AS update_time, sp.play_time AS play_time
    FROM session_player sp
    INNER JOIN players p ON p.id=sp.player_id
    WHERE p.name = ?
) as pd
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT sp.id as max_id, p.name as player, max(update_time) as last_seen, 
min(login_time) as first_seen, s.name as last_server,
sum(sp.play_time) as ontime_total,
sum(case when login_time > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY then sp.play_time end) as ontime_day,
sum(case when login_time > NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY then sp.play_time end) as ontime_week,
sum(case when login_time > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH then sp.play_time end) as ontime_month
FROM session_player sp
INNER JOIN players p ON p.id=sp.player_id
INNER JOIN server s ON s.id=sp.server_id
WHERE p.name = ?
group by sp.player_id
order by sp.id desc limit 1
```

Comment: I tried it similar, but it only gives one record so there is nothing to group or sort.